# Using Twitter Bootstrap Form fields instead of Spring form

Tags: spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Twitter Bootstrap is working fine in my application. But, how do I work this part out. I want to get the path="name" inside the twitter bootstrap input field.

*Spring Form*

```
<tr>
    <td>Product Name:</td>
    <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
```

*Twitter Bootstrap*

```
<div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Name" />
</div>
```

Tired this. But, gave me a "Unknown Tag" Warning.

```
<form:input path="name" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Name" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to do spring form:input functionality using bootstrap alone? I don't think "path" will appear in the generated html. It uses "name" property instead.

Have you tried:

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="inputEmail"  />
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to add

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

at the top of your JSP file.

Interesting link : [Using Spring's form tag library](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-configuration)

Comment: I did that before. Gave me a warning "Unknown Tag".